# Command line glyphs (ZSH + powerline)

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, zsh, powerline

I am currently using Windows 10 with CYGWIN. Its using mintty and running ZSH in xterm-256.

I have been searching *all night* and cannot find a place to find all powerline glyphs for use in the ZSH prompt, I am *very* new to this so don't expect me to know anything.

For example, the 'svn branch' and 'git untracked (like 3 dots)'. I don't know whether these are unicode or something or other so **any** information on what they are and how to use them would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts you are looking for can be found [here](https://github.com/powerline/fonts). Installation instructions from the official documentation:

1. Download the latest version of the symbol font and fontconfig file:

   `wget https://github.com/powerline/powerline/raw/develop/font/PowerlineSymbols.otf`

   `wget https://github.com/powerline/powerline/raw/develop/font/10-powerline-symbols.conf`
2. Move the symbol font to a valid X font path. Valid font paths can be listed with `xset q`:

   `mv PowerlineSymbols.otf ~/.fonts/`
3. Update font cache for the path the font was moved to (root priveleges may be needed to update cache for the system-wide paths):

   `fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts/`
4. Install the fontconfig file. For newer versions of fontconfig the config path is`~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/`, for older versions it’s `~/.fonts.conf.d/`:

   `mv 10-powerline-symbols.conf ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/`

You can find detailed documentation [here](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/linux.html#font-installation).